# Using Stroom to parse Snort log files

Tags: xml, parsing, logging, snort

I've been working with Stroom for the past 2 days and have been trying to parse snort log files in this pattern

```
<stroom-event>
<date>2017/10/17</date>
<time>11:30:02.43</time>
<srcip>172.16.0.1</srcip>
<srcport>334</srcport>
<dstip>172.16.0.100</dstip>
<dstport>25</dstport>
</stroom-event>
```

I made a DSparser and coded this inside it

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <dataSplitter xmlns="data-splitter:3" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="data-splitter:3 file://data-splitter-v3.0.xsd" 
   version="3.0">
    <split delimiter="\n">
      <group value="$1">
        <regex pattern="r'([0-9/]+)-([0-9:.]+)\s+.*?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})\s+->\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})'">
          <data name="date" value="$1"/>
          <data name="time" value="$2"/>
          <data name="srcip" value="$3"/>
          <data name="srcport" value="$4"/>
          <data name="dstip" value="$5"/>
          <data name="dstport" value="$6"/>
        </regex>
      </group>
    </split>
    </dataSplitter>
```

When I start the feed and test if it is parsing anything I'm getting nothing. Any help would be appreciated!